# Memcached returns always empty string without failure

Tags: memcached, plesk

Memcached was working but ( after Plesk update ) not working anymore.

This is a simple code from PHP memcached page.

```
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer('127.0.0.1',11211);
if( $mem->add("mystr","this is a memcache test!",3600)){
   echo 'Success';
}else{
    echo 'Error:'.$mem->get("mystr");
}
print_r( $mem->get("mystr") ); // NOTHING!
```

Memcached is installed through PECL. Plesk Obsidian ( Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS ) is set to automatic update and is updated several days ago...

Now i get nothing from Memcached. I checked some error logs. They seem to be clear. Maybe the problem is about IGbinary or serializer... Clean install doesn't work too. Memcached is there but doesn't write anything to memory and always return empty string.

The steps i take to uninstall

```
/opt/plesk/php/8.1/bin/pecl uninstall memcached
plesk bin php_handler --reread
service plesk-php81-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

To Install

```
apt-get update && apt-get install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config plesk-php81-dev zlib1g-dev libmemcached-dev
apt install memcached autoconf automake gcc libmemcached-dev libhashkit-dev pkg-config plesk-php*-dev zlib1g-dev
/opt/plesk/php/8.1/bin/pecl install memcached
```

Options

```
libmemcached - no
zlib - yes
fastlz - no
igbinary - yes ( changed to no, this doesn't help )
msgpack - no
json serializer - yes
server protocol - no
sasl - yes
sessions - yes
```

Adding it to php.ini

```
echo "extension=memcached.so" > /opt/plesk/php/8.1/etc/php.d/memcached.ini
```

nano /etc/memcached.conf

```
#-p 11211
#-l 127.0.0.1
-c 4096
-m 128
-I 5242880


chown -R memcache:memcache /var/run/memcached
chmod 2750 /var/run/memcached
```

php.ini

```
 session.save_path = "/var/run/memcached/memcached.sock:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
```

Finally restart...

```
plesk bin php_handler --reread
service plesk-php81-fpm restart
service apache2 restart
```

Test

`/opt/plesk/php/8.1/bin/php -m | grep memcached`

I get Memcached... Everything seems ok. But i still get only empty string.

I changed dedicated FPM to FPM ( I know Memcached has nothing to do with FPM but just tried... ) Still not working.

Some library dependencies must be broken (there is no error during installation). Any ideas how to fix it or how to install it ( step by step on plesk without PECL ).